# Clickable TextView

Tags: java, android

Текст приходит в `TextView` автоматически с ВК, в нем есть ссылки, хочу сделать так что бы при нажатии на эту ссылку она открывалась в своем браузере (мною написанном).

Но при передаче ссылки из `PostAdapter`, вылетает ошибка.

```
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mShowStyle;
    VKPostArray obj;
    VKApiPost p;
    VKApiPhoto vkPhoto;
    ArrayList<String> imgUrls1;
    VKApiUser mainUser;
    Context ctx;
    private int lastPosition = -1;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, VKPostArray posts, VKApiUser user, int showStyle) {
        super();
        this.obj = posts;
        this.mainUser = user;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mShowStyle = showStyle;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position) {

        p = obj.get(position);

        holder.textPost.setText(p.text);
        holder.textPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent15 = new Intent(ctx, Browser.class);
                intent15.putExtra("link", "LINK");
                intent15.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ctx.startActivity(intent15);
            }
        });
```

---

Ошибка такая:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName() on a null object reference
    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4449)
    at calculation.material.oma.sviter.by.PostAdapter$1.onClick(PostAdapter.java:73)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас **ctx** == **null** по всей видимости.

Добавьте следующую строчку в конструктор:

```
public PostAdapter(Context context, VKPostArray posts, VKApiUser user, int showStyle) {
    super();
    ctx = context;
    ....
}
```